# Is there a way to prevent JOIN from joining new data sets with old?

Tags: python, sqlite

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("lite.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM database JOIN database1")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
        tree.insert("", tk.END, values=row)
    conn.close()
```

I have two SQLite3 databases, database and database1. When I join database1 to database and the user enters all of the information to be stored in the database it joins them as expected. However, if the user adds a new set of data the old set joins the new set again.

E.g. user enters: Frank in database and Apple in database1
Displayed results: Frank Apple

user enter: William in database and Orange in database1
Displayed results: Frank Apple
                   Frank Orange
                   William Orange
                   William Apple

How do I stop the database from modifying any other stored values?

Expected: Frank Apple
          William Orange

Comment: You stop this by specifying *join conditions*, that restrict how rows from both tables combine, using an `on` clause: `FROM database JOIN database1. ON <conditions>`

Comment: you doesn't join databases but tables. Maybe you should keep all data in one table. OR you will have to create "relation" between values - ie. keep Orange with William's ID and then you can join them by ID. So you have to learn SQL and how databases work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't JOIN databases, you JOIN tables. To use multiple databases in a connection you open/connect one database and ATTACH the other databases with a schema so as to differentiate them, the originally connected database will have a schema name of main.

If you don't provide conditions for a JOIN then every permutation/combination will be the result.

- You use `ON the_condition(s)`

As a Demo of ATTACH and JOIN with and without conditions :-

```
import sqlite3

# First database
connection1 = sqlite3.connect("database")
connection1.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)")
connection1.commit()
connection1.execute("DELETE FROM table1")
connection1.execute("INSERT INTO table1 (name) VALUES('Frank'),('Mary'),('Joan')")
connection1.commit()
cursor = connection1.execute("SELECT * FROM table1")
print("\nData in table1 (in 1st Database)")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)

# Second database
connection2 = sqlite3.connect("database1")
connection2.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)")
connection2.commit()
connection2.execute("DELETE FROM table2")
connection2.execute("INSERT INTO table2 (name) VALUES('Apple'),('Banana'),('Pear')")
connection2.commit()
cursor = connection2.execute("SELECT * FROM table2")
print("\nData in table 2 (in 2nd Database)")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)

connection2.close()

# Attach 2nd database to first
connection1.execute("ATTACH DATABASE 'database1' AS schema_database2")
connection1.commit()
# Use a JOIN
cursor = connection1.execute("SELECT * FROM main.table1 JOIN schema_database2.table2 ON table1.id = table2.id")
print("\nJoin Example 1 (schema not needed)")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)

# If there is no ambiguity of names (table names) then just table name can be used
print("\nJoin Example 2 (schema not needed)")
cursor = connection1.execute("SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)

print("\nNatural (not recommended ) Join")
cursor = connection1.execute("SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

## Demo Result :-

> ```
> Data in table1 (in 1st Database)
> (1, 'Frank')
> (2, 'Mary')
> (3, 'Joan')
>
> Data in table 2 (in 2nd Database)
> (1, 'Apple')
> (2, 'Banana')
> (3, 'Pear')
>
> Join Example 1 (schema not needed)
> (1, 'Frank', 1, 'Apple')
> (2, 'Mary', 2, 'Banana')
> (3, 'Joan', 3, 'Pear')
>
> Join Example 2 (schema not needed)
> (1, 'Frank', 1, 'Apple')
> (2, 'Mary', 2, 'Banana')
> (3, 'Joan', 3, 'Pear')
>
> Without JOIN conditions (joins everything to everything)
> (1, 'Frank', 1, 'Apple')
> (1, 'Frank', 2, 'Banana')
> (1, 'Frank', 3, 'Pear')
> (2, 'Mary', 1, 'Apple')
> (2, 'Mary', 2, 'Banana')
> (2, 'Mary', 3, 'Pear')
> (3, 'Joan', 1, 'Apple')
> (3, 'Joan', 2, 'Banana')
> (3, 'Joan', 3, 'Pear')
>
> Process finished with exit code 0
> ```